# CORS proxy (php) fails to connect to port

Tags: php, proxy, cors

When I make a request in the browser address bar to http://fmgold.mvserver.be:4101/7.html, I receive the metadata correctly.

In my app, the requests to the given path are failing because of CORS problems. I do not have access to the server to modify the headers, so I'm trying to create a CORS proxy with PHP.

```
<?php
if( ! isset($curl_timeout))
    $curl_timeout = 30;

$headers = getallheaders();
$method = __('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER);
$url = $_GET['url'];

// Check that we have a URL
if( ! $url)
    http_response_code(400) and exit("Url missing");

foreach($headers as $key => &$value) {
    $value = "$key: $value";
}

$curl = curl_init();
do
{
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_PORT => 4101,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $curl_timeout,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE
        ]);
    // Method specific options
    switch($method)
    {
        case 'HEAD':
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
            break;
        case 'GET':
            break;
        case 'PUT':
        case 'POST':
        case 'DELETE':
        default:
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('php://input'));
            break;
    }
    // Perform request
    ob_start();
    curl_exec($curl) or http_response_code(500) and exit(curl_error($curl));
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    $url = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
}

while($url and --$maxredirs > 0);

$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Remove any existing headers
header_remove();

// Use gz, if acceptable
// ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Output headers
$header = substr($out, 0, $info['header_size']);
array_map('header', explode("\r\n", $header));

// And finally the body
echo substr($out, $info['header_size']);

// Helper function
function __($key, array $array, $default = null)
{
    return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

I have the PHP running on a live server, but when I call the url through the proxy php `(http://cors-proxy.myliveserver.com/proxy.php?url=http://fmgold.mvserver.be/7.html`, I am getting the following error response:

`Failed to connect to fmgold.mvserver.be port 4101: Connection refused`

Adding the port to the curl request does not seem to help. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. Works perfectly and outputs '1,1,10,10,1,64,CLAUDIA JUNG & CLAYDERMAN - JE T'AIME MON AMOUR'. Maybe a temporary hickup on their servers?

Comment: if CORS blocks this port highly unlikely you can do it, becos sole reason why you have CORS enabled is to avoid these types of security issues from untrusted locations

Comment: @mahen3d I have successfully achieved retrieving the contents of the target url by using the cors-anywhere solution deployed as a heroku app (see https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). So I am trying to achieve the same with PHP on my server. So it should be possible, right?

Comment: @ElFred how do you know its CORS that is causing the "Connection refused", as "Connection refused" can be many different reason. can you post the error log that proof the issue is related to the CORS?

Comment: (There seems to be someone who gives -1 to all CORS questions and answers, StackOverflow should ban this one.)

Answer (score 0):

Three things,

1. Server-side calls are not subject to Cross-Origin-Request policy
   unless you're adding '**Origin**' header to the request
2. You don't need to set port in the curl request. `CURLOPT_PORT => 4101,` this is not required
3. When you're calling this url `http://fmgold.mvserver.be:4101/7.html`
   from browser, there is no '**Origin**' header involved and you get
   the response by making **GET** request to it.

   But at server side, when you're making the request,
   what you're doing is, you're fetching the Server headers `$headers = getallheaders();` and setting all of them in your curl request
   `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,` and executing it.

   My assumption is `$headers` contain '**Origin**' header and the
   host server is denying your request with CORS because of this

   Remove this `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,` and try. It should
   work